# Long boot time (~15 minutes)

Tags: windows-xp, boot, performance

I recently formatted the drive and re-installed Windows XP. I now get a bar across the lower part of the screen during start up, like when recovering from hibernation, and it takes 15-17 minutes to start up.

I tried to change the boot sequence in the BIOS advanced options, but nothing changed.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Test your hard drive and memory for problems...http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/How-to-test-RAM-and-HDD-Hard-Drive/td-p/301638

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen when waking from hibernation only, or also on first boot?

Go by eliminitation by unplugging USB devices (except mouse/keyb) and external hard drives - sometimes windows can hang a while having trouble to "detect" one of them.

Check if BIOS firmware updates exist for your motherboard (read the description to see if it could apply). Also search on google for your computer or motherboard model and see if it's a known issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Actually it happens on first boot, and ext. hard drives are plugged but are switched off when I turn the computer on. I encountered the same problem when I formatted the HDD last year but do not remember how it got rid of that! I am going to search for updates for the motherboard. Thanks a lot again!